# Oracle SQL: Regex for finding out values from a Stringified map of fixed format

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a String in a specific column of my table which is of a certain fixed format.

For ex:

`Score breakup: {TR_SCORE=0, SAR_SCORE=2, LO_SCORE=2, CASH_SCORE=1, TPP_SCORE=1, CREDITS_SCORE=1}`

I wish to write a regex to separate out all the scoring values as below:

```
SELECT TR_SCORE, SAR_SCORE, LO_SCORE 
  FROM some_table 
 WHERE message LIKE 'Score breakup:%';
```

| TR_SCORE | SAR_SCORE | LO_SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 |

Can anyone help create a regex for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` function along with `\d+` pattern in order to extract the substrings with digits only such as

```sql
SELECT col,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(col,'(.*TR_SCORE=)(\d+)(.*)','\2') AS tr_score,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(col,'(.*SAR_SCORE=)(\d+)(.*)','\2') AS sar_score,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(col,'(.*LO_SCORE=)(\d+)(.*)','\2') AS lo_score
  FROM t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=410739b7240c1dc4a6e07f2f351d7727)</kbd>